# CakePHP 2.x helper class to export as Excel spreadsheets

Tags: cakephp-2.0, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a data view to Excel format but can't find a helper that works with Cake 2.x

The closest I found was http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/wasenbr/2007/04/12/excel-xls-helper but that throws errors like this

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'XlsHelper' does not have a method 'beforeRender'
```

Does anybody have a link to a helper that will work in newer versions of Cake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helper works if you just add blank functions for all the errors that appear.